# simple silverlight databinding listbox to List<>

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

It seems like this should be simple...
I have a usercontrol that I am going to use on several tabs of a tab control.  I want all instances of the usercontrol to be synchronized.

In my usercontrol I have a list of strings:

```
public static List<string> fonts = new List<string>() { "Arial", "Courier" };
```

And a ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="fontList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=fonts}" />
```

However, the listbox is never populated.
In searching for example code, it seems like I have seen this implementation in several samples, but I can't get it to work.
Thanks for any hints...

**Updated** with AWJ's suggestions, but still not working:
MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public static List<string> _fonts
        = new List<string>() { "Arial", "Courier" };

    public List<string> Fonts { get { return _fonts;  } }
}
```

In TestGroup.xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="fontList1" ItemsSource="{Binding Parent.Fonts, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"  Margin="3" />
```

Answer (score 4):

- First of all you can only bind to Properties not Fields.
- Second the Property needs to be an instance property to support binding
- Third unless you make the UserControl its own DataContext you need a more sophisticated binding.

In code you will need:-

```
public static List<string> fonts = new List<string>() { "Arial", "Courier" };
public List<string> Fonts {get { return fonts; } }
```

and in xaml:-

```
<ListBox x:Name="fontlist" ItemsSource="{Binding Parent.Fonts, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />
```